# BoxPlot: How to display yearly value instead of quarterly value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn, boxplot

I have a dataframe that contains the columns, "quarter" and "resale-price". I used the dataframe to plot a boxplot, using seaborn. The boxplot displays the quarterly value such as (2007-Q2, 2007-Q3, 2007-Q4, 2008-Q2). However, I want it to display the yearly value such as (2007, 2008, 2009). How can I achieve that?

```
import seaborn as sns

data = {
    'quarter': ['2007-Q2', '2007-Q2', '2007-Q2', '2007-Q2', '2007-Q3', 
            '2007-Q3', '2007-Q3', '2007-Q3', '2007-Q4', '2007-Q4', 
            '2007-Q4', '2007-Q4', '2008-Q2', '2008-Q2', '2008-Q2', 
            '2008-Q2','2008-Q3', '2008-Q3', '2008-Q3', '2008-Q3',  
            '2008-Q4', '2008-Q4', '2008-Q4', '2008-Q4', '2009-Q2', 
            '2009-Q2', '2009-Q2', '2009-Q2', '2009-Q3', '2009-Q3', 
            '2009-Q3', '2009-Q3', '2009-Q4', '2009-Q4', '2009-Q4',
            '2009-Q4',  '2010-Q2','2010-Q2', '2010-Q2', '2010-Q2',
            '2010-Q3', '2010-Q3', '2010-Q3', '2010-Q3', '2010-Q4',
            '2010-Q4', '2010-Q4', '2010-Q4'],

'resale_price': [172000, 260000, 372000, 172000, 224500, 224500, 
                311500, 358800, 438000, 344000, 182200, 261300, 372000, 
                172000, 224500, 224240, 311500, 358800, 438000, 344900,
                172000, 260000, 372000, 172000, 224500, 224500, 311500, 
                358800, 438000, 394000, 172400, 360000, 172000, 472000, 
                254500, 226510, 321600, 358800, 438800, 394000, 155400, 
                465000, 232000, 475090, 244520, 236518, 321100, 398901]
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
ax = sns.boxplot(data = df, x='quarter', y='resale_price')

for item in ax.get_xticklabels():
   item.set_rotation(90)
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`set_xticklabels`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html) with indexing - first 4 values of strings, also set `rotation`:

```
ax.set_xticklabels(df['quarter'].str[:4], rotation='vertical')
```

And loop should be removed:

```
for item in ax.get_xticklabels():
   item.set_rotation(90)
```

---

If need for each year separate boxplot:

```
df['year'] = df['quarter'].str[:4]
ax = sns.boxplot(data = df, x='year', y='resale_price')
```

Comment: Hi jezrael, what if the number of quarter varies? For example, 2017-Q2 have 10 values, 2017-Q3 have 5 values and etc? The code that I've posted was just a sample, I actually have a CSV file that contains around 3000 rows, where the number of quarter varies

Comment: @Issaki - Not sure if understand, just test your real data and ploting nice.

Comment: Is it okay if i contact you via email for further explanation?

Comment: I've sent an email to you.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the question, you would like to have only 4 boxes, one per year. That could be accomplished by extracting the year out of the "quarter" column and using the new "year" column as input to the seaborn function.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

data = # ... as defined in question

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["year"], _ = df['quarter'].str.split('-', 1).str

plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
ax = sns.boxplot(data = df, x='year', y='resale_price')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, or simplier `df['year'] = df['quarter'].str[:4]` like in my answer.